How to disable the GIL in python3.13?
I am excited to experiment with python3.13 with new GIL optional feature. I want to explore the impact of disabling GIL to achieve real multi-threading in python.
I want a real world example to compare the python3.13 performance for multi-threading with GIL enabled and disabled.
In the same environment, can i run two python one with GIL and other without GIL?
REF: PEP703

Have you downloaded the 3.13 experimental free-threaded binaries? If so, you should have a version of python3.13 with the GIL enable and python3.13t with it disabled.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

According to the What's new in Python 3.13, you need a new Python binary to test it.

The free-threaded mode requires a different executable, usually called python3.13t or python3.13t.exe.

Using pyenv latest version to install Python, this should give you a virtual environment to test it (in most unix systems):
pyenv install 3.13t-dev
$HOME/.pyenv/versions/3.13t-dev/bin/python3.13t -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate

You can check it with sys._is_gil_enabled()
python -c 'import sys; print(sys._is_gil_enabled())'
# you should get 'False'


Ubunt users can use:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.13-nogil


Ubunt users can use:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.13-nogil

